# Internet Explorer and JavaScript event currentTarget

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events

Is there a way to take the current target of an event with IE 7 or 8?

With other browser (firefox, opera, chrome etc.) we can use
`event.currentTarget` or also we can use the `this` keyword to
refer to the object processing the event.

But in **Internet Explorer** we don't have `currentTarget` property and the `this` refers to window object!

So how can I do that?

Comment: yes I did it. But no answer founded...it seems that IE simply does not support that important feature (also IE 8) and every time I must develop with that browser the NIGHTMARES begin!

Comment: you could always go down the JavaScript framework route like jQuery, Prototype, etc... to abstract the differences away

Comment: It is more than nine years later and jQuery still does not guarantee in the API-documentation that event.currentTarget will work as expected. When even they do not accomplish it after so many years, it is an impossible feat.

Answer (score 32):

You can do something like

```
target = (event.currentTarget) ? event.currentTarget : event.srcElement;
```

Although as @Marc mentioned you can use a JQuery framework that normalizes the event for you.

Comment: Reference for srcElement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534638(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Useful but incomplete. Reading here ( http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/eventinfo ) I found out that you have to put "if(window.event){ event = window.event; }" before your code.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting, that link would definitely help out in understanding browsers older than most current ones and if they run in quirks mode.

Comment: That’s not correct, event.srcElement equals event.target. event.currentTarget is something else and is more difficult to normalize.

Comment: Looks like @David is right, see the end of http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: Hmm interesting, what would you recommend to normalize it @David/@Marc?

Comment: @alvincrespo it depends, if you don’t need to remove the listener you can just bring in the element into the callback using an anonymous function and .call() since e.currentTarget == bound element. Otherwise I would save the callbacks in an array or use a good event lib like found in jQuery, YUI or independent libs ( I use my own called 2k.js ).

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. srcElement is the original source of the event, not necessarily the current target.

Answer (score 25):

I had similar problem. I solved it using keyword `this` as stated in [an article on brainjar.com](http://www.brainjar.com/dhtml/events/default3.asp)

> To get the equivalent of the currentTarget property in IE, use the
>   this keyword as an argument when setting the event handler in a tag.
>
> ...
>
> function myHandler(event, link) {   ... }

On the same page you can find the following table :

[image]

Answer (score 13):

The short answer is: use jQuery.

Although `event.currentTarget` is not accessible on IE, jQuery will normalize the event for you so your code would also work on IE (as stated [here](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/05/12/jquery-edge-bind-with-a-different-this))

Note that using `event.srcElement`, as suggested in other answers is **not** equivalent, since `srcElement` corresponds to the `target`, not to `currentTarget`, as explained at the end of [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. And it doesn't offer any solutions. :(

Comment: @alvincrespo: How is my first line ("Use jQuery") not a solution? If the OP uses jQuery, he will be able to use `event.currentTarget` on IE 7/8, as per his request.

Comment: I guess it is an answer but I was under the assumption that @xdevel2000 was asking for a pure JS answer. I apologize for any misunderstanding and not explaining my comment.

Comment: @alvincrespo: No problem. It is nice that you give a pure JS answer (you got my upvote :-). I'll stick with my opinion that cross browser subtleties are best handled  through existing solutions (e.g. jQuery) than figuring out where it doesn't work and bypassing the issue "by hand".

Comment: I know this is old but downvoted as the jQ route requires the event to be passed to the function.  As far as getting the event target *without explicitely passing the event object to the function*, alvincrespo's method is the only way that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Farray: tks. Is it the same, though? As @David comments, `srcElement == target`, not `currentTarget`. See also end of http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: @Marc Thanks for the reply -- I totally missed that and David/you are correct.

Comment: Since the small script that I'm dealing with was already using jquery, I simply replaced `$(e.currentTarget)` with `$(this)`. If you're in with jquery, go all-in.

Answer (score 2):

with this function you can pass the object when adding and get it in the listener.
the problem about this is that you have an anonymous function as eventlistener and in actionscript you cannot remove an anonymous listener. dunno bout js.

```
addEvent:function(object,type,listener,param)
    {
    if(object.addEventListener)
      object.addEventListener(type, function(e){ listener(object, e, param);}, false );
    else
    if(object.attachEvent)
      object.attachEvent('on'+type, function(e){ e = getEvent(e); listener(object, e, param);});
    },

getEvent:function(e)
        {
    if(!e) e = window.event; // || event
    if(e.srcElement) e.target = e.srcElement;
    return e;
    },

removeEvent:function(object,type,listener)
    {
    if(object.removeEventListener)
    object.removeEventListener(type, listener, false);
    else
    object.detachEvent('on'+type, listener);
    }

var div = document.getElementById('noobsafediv');
var div2 = document.getElementById('noobsafediv2');
addEvent(div,'mouseover',mouseover,['astring',111,div2]);


function mouseover(object,e,param)
 {
 console.log(object,e,param);
 }
```

its my framework and i call it jNoob.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're wanting to use the 'this' context because the same handler will be dealing with multliple posible objects.  In that case, see the excellent AddEvent script from the quirksmode recoding contest. (http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/addevent_recodi.html).  This code has allowed me to get the very last of my javascript out of html.  More importantly, it seems to work on all of the browsers that I've tested.  Simple and compact.

Answer (score 1):

Additional note: Sometimes IE (like ie 7) will return undefined for event.target, so it won't even evaluate it as true or false (whether in an if or in a ternary operator). Furthermore, even if you try `typeof event.target == 'undefined'` it will still error saying "event.target is undefined." Which of course is stupid because that's what you're testing. 
Apparently it is a problem with passing events into functions in older IE. What you do to fix it is:

```
event = event ? event : window.event;
if (typeof event.target == 'undefined') {
    var target = event.srcElement;
    } else {
    var target = event.target;
    }
```

Make note that you re-write the event in standards compliant browsers and grab the global event for IE.

Comment: Note that event.target refers to the element the event was fired on, whereas *event.currentTarget* (the one in the question) is the element the event is being handled by, i.e. the one you set the handler on. The event.target element is the innermost element, for example, in a click event. See here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing.

Answer (score 1):

This function creates `currentTarget` in case it is IE, so you no longer need to patch your code!

```
function eventListener(e,t,f) {
   if(e.addEventListener)
       e.addEventListener(t,f);
   else
       e.attachEvent('on' + t,
                     function(a){
                         a.currentTarget = e;
                         f(a);
                     });
}
```

Regular JS(will not work on IE below 9):

```
function myfunction(e) {
    alert(e.currentTarget.id);
}

e = document.getElementById('id');
e.AddEventListener(e,'mouseover',myfunction);
```

With this function(will work on IE below 9):

```
function myfunction(e) {
    alert(e.currentTarget.id);
}
e = document.getElementById('id');
eventListener(e,'mouseover',myfunction);
```

Comment: Really?  You think "those jQuery guys" don't want people to know this?  Their code is open source, I expect Resig does not care.

Comment: Really? So why I'm the only one who wrote such solution here?

Comment: It looks almost the same as anas' answer to me.  But if you are paranoid and want a us vs them situation, feel that way :D

Comment: Not what I want to do that, but everywhere where I look, I see Jquery. It feels like soon people will not be able to hide a div by id without Jquery.

Comment: Very very true... there is an on-going joke / meme on Meta and other places about how every javascript question's answer starts with "Use jQuery and..."  However, this question was not about jQuery and there is an attempt on SO to not have POV questions or answers.  There is nothing interesting or relevant about bashing the "jQuery guys".  That was my point.

Answer (score 1):

With Prototype JS you can use :

```
var target = Event.element(event);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Internet Explorer 6 - 8** do not implement event.currentTarget.

Quote from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget#Browser_compatibility):

> On Internet Explorer 6 through 8, the event model is different. Event listeners are attached with the non-standard element.attachEvent method. In this model, there is no equivalent to event.currentTarget and this is the global object. **One solution to emulate the event.currentTarget feature is to wrap your handler in a function calling the handler using Function.prototype.call with the element as a first argument. This way, this will be the expected value.**

If you use **jQuery** anyway, then jQuery takes care of normalizing the event object and its properties (as stated numerous times in the other answers). Quote from [jQuery API docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/):

> jQuery’s event system normalizes the event object according to W3C standards.

Answer (score 0):

[currentTarget property is supported from IE version 9 onwards.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Try this sample in IE9+](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_event_currenttarget)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to give a more simple answer, the meat of this is the same as the meat in anas' and user1515360's answers:

```
if (browserDoesNotUnderstandCurrentTarget) {
        someElement.onclick = function (e) {
                if (!e) { var e = window.event; }
                e.currentTarget = someElement;
                yourCallback(e);
        }
}
else {
        someElement.onclick = yourCallback;
}
```

Substitute onclick for whatever event you wish of course.

This makes e.currentTarget available on browsers that do not support currentTarget.

Answer (score 0):

well i m not sure but this may be a solution:
since the child element given by srcElement is not supposed to have an event because this gonna make interference with the event on the parent element neither any other upper element before the top element where the event statement (like onmosedown="") so this is the code:

```
if (!event) event = window.event; 
if (event.currentTarget) element = event.currentTarget; 
else{element = event.srcElement; while(element.onmousedown==null) element = element.parentNode;}
if(element.nodeType==3) element=element.parentNode;  // defeat Safari bug
```

this seems to work fine till now with me please correct me if u find a problem cz i need a solution for that
i dont want to use jquery..

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a **closure** and pass in the element the event handler has been attached to. Something along these lines...

```
function handlerOnClick (currentTarget) {
    return function () {
        console.log(currentTarget);
    } 
}

var domElement = document.createElement('DIV');
domElement.innerHTML = 'Click me!';
domElement.onclick = handlerOnClick(domElement);
document.body.appendChild(domElement);
```