# Switch Style Radio Button Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button

I would like to know how I can make a switch style function to change the website style between 2 styles. Here's what I have done so far. Please check. Thank you.

```
function switchcss() {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="css/style1.css">'); 
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="css/style2.css">'); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/APbSm/

Comment: I tried cleaning up the code styling here.

Comment: When radio button selected the page loads into white screen, nothing happens..!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how one can use JavaScript to create/remove DOM elements, including `link`.

Please, read, e.g. [dynamically loading / removing js and css](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)

Also, it is not a good idea to use document.write() in most circumstances. I could write you a full correct solution, but there is no "common" universal couple of lines for that, and if you have to have a skin switcher, and need to support it in the future, it makes much more sense to understand the technology underneath.

Comment: thank you for your  source, basically im dont know much about javascriipt ,  so if it iss possible for you just write me fucntion which would enbale me to switch from .css style sheet , for example i do like to make different .css styles and in future just as the link to the function, so if possible pleas help. very appericiate it. thanks

Comment: Gabriel's answer provides a very much working solution. You can use it, but on your own site. jsfiddle is great for many things, but in your case it will be particularly difficult to understand the code there, even if it is made to work - `link` elements and external css resources are are outside of the editable scope.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to *skin a cat*, here is one approach, using jQuery:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Switch Style Radio Button Using JavaScript</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>

<input type="radio" name="switch" id="style1" value="Theme 1" checked="checked" />Theme 1<br />
<input type="radio" name="switch" id="style2" value="Theme 2" />Theme 2

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#style1').click(function() {
        $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr({
            href: 'css/style1.css'
        });
    });

    $('#style2').click(function() {
        $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr({
            href: 'css/style2.css'
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I realize this is not the best approach, but answers the original poster's question with as little code as possible — kudos that it can essentially be copied, pasted, and implemented with ease.

However, a greater understanding of the problem can yield a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation. It borrows much of the event handler logic from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857439/internet-explorer-and-javascript-event-currenttarget). YOU SHOULD NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION. There is nothing worse than copying and pasting code you do not understand. Read and practice, when you fully understand this code you will be able to write a much better implementation that you will be able to maintain and support.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" id="switch_style"/>
```

JS stuff:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
  function getEvent (e) {
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    if(e.srcElement) e.target = e.srcElement;
    return e;
  }
  function addEvent (object,type,listener,param) {
    if(object.addEventListener) {
      object.addEventListener(type, 
        function(e){ 
          listener.call(object, e, param);
        }, 
        false );
    } else if(object.attachEvent) {
      object.attachEvent('on'+type, 
        function(e){ 
          e = getEvent(e); 
          listener.call(object, e, param);
        }
      );
    }
  }
  var default_style = 1,
      container = document.getElementById('switch_container'),
      controls = container.childNodes,
      styles = document.getElementById('switch_style');
  function switch_style(event){
    event = getEvent(event);
    s = event.target.getAttribute('value');
    styles.setAttribute('href, 'style' + s + '.css');
  }
  [].map.call(controls, function( e, i, l ){
    if( e.nodeType === 1 && e.getAttribute('type') === 'radio' ) {
      addEvent( e, 'click', switch_style );
    }
  })
  // bind the function to the event handler.
})()
</script>
```

DOM stuff:

```
<div id="switch_container">
  <input type="radio" name="switch" value="1"/>style 1<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="switch" value="2"/>style 2<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="switch" value="3"/>style 3<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="switch" value="4"/>style 4<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="switch" value="5"/>style 5<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="switch" value="6"/>style 6<br/>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zj7Bm/2/)

Comment: Have you tried it in the common browsers? I am just curious. I usually replace the whole `link` element, for the fear that changing `href` might create unwanted compatibility problems somewhere down the road.

Comment: thank you , was very helpfull but can you please tell me how can make a function to use several style sheet to be changed by using radio button. thanks.

Comment: I have written out the event bindings and the html. Because you have not defined what your style files will look like I have assumed style + number + .css and so am using the value property of the radio buttons. They will trigger the style change of click.

Answer (score 0):

also, it is better to use: first-of-type pseudo class if there is more than one stylesheet

```
<script>
$('#style1').click(function() {
    $('link[rel="stylesheet"]:first-of-type').attr({
        href: 'css/style1.css'
    });
});

$('#style2').click(function() {
    $('link[rel="stylesheet"]:first-of-type').attr({
        href: 'css/style2.css'
    });
});</script>
```