# event.currentTarget in IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I've got an event handler that I'm attaching to an element to catch a bubbled click event.
I need a **reliable** way of obtaining the element that **caught** the event, not the element that triggered it.
The amount of levels this specific element is above the srcElement/target is arbitrary, thus using parentNode or whatever is not a viable solution.
This specifically needs to work in IE6.
While I am a bit of a fan of the jQuery framework, I **will not** be using jQuery in this, so any jQuery suggestions will be considered useless.

tl;dr: I need a **reliable** event.currentTarget in IE6, no jQuery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857439/internet-explorer-and-javascript-event-currenttarget

Comment: What's wrong with `this`? Inside the event handler, `this` refers to the DOM element the handler is attached to.

Comment: @Felix what happens if you want to pass the event or target to another function to work out something like offsets.

Comment: @Endophage: Then you just pass `this` to that function... or you set `event.currentTarget` to `this`.

Comment: @Felix so in a function to get the offset of the mouse within the element that triggered the event you would pass the element as `this` and also the event object which already contains the element?

Comment: @Felix in IE6 this is not the case.  In IE6-8 `this` refers to `window` when in the context of an event handler.

Comment: @Endophage: I would pass `this` if I need it. If the event handler is bound to some other element than the one the handler is attached to but I want to compute the offset for the element the event was triggered on, I obviously don't have to pass `this`.

Comment: I always ask this whenever IE6 is mentioned: Are you *sure* IE 6 is a client-driven requirement? It has only 10% market share, and it is incompatible with even YouTube. Heck, the operating system it runs on reaches EOL in less than 3 years.

Comment: @user752854: Are you really sure? I have not heard of this. quirksmode.org does not mention it either.

Comment: @Felix http://jsfiddle.net/AXUSN/ Try it out in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** `attachEvent` really seems to create a problem here. [From quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html):

> In the following cases this refers to the window:
>
> ```
> element.onclick = function () {doSomething()}
> element.attachEvent('onclick',doSomething)
> <element onclick="doSomething()">
> ```
>
> Note the presence of `attachEvent()`. The main drawback of the [Microsoft event registration model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) is that `attachEvent()` creates a reference to the function and does not copy it. Therefore it is sometimes impossible to know which HTML currently handles the event.

The only way how you could solve this seems to be by creating a wrapper, something like:

```
var addListener = (function() {
    if(document.attachEvent) {
        return function(element, event, handler) {
            element.attachEvent('on' + event, function() {
                var event = window.event;
                event.currentTarget = element;
                event.target = event.srcElement;
                handler.call(element, event);
            });
        };
     }
     else {
        return function(element, event, handler) {
            element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
        };
     }
}());
```

Then `this` would refer to the element, as would `event.currentTarget` and you'd pass `event` as first argument.

Usage:

```
addListener(element, 'click', function(e) {
    // this refers to element
    // e.currentTarget refers to element
    // e.target refers to the element that triggered the event
});
```

---

**Old answer:** (which works for *inline* and *traditional* event handlers, as well as `addEventListener` (but not `attachEvent`))

Inside the event handler, `this` refers to the element the event handler is attached to.

Comment: Again, in IE6 this is not the case.  In IE6-8 `this` refers to `window` when in the context of an event handler.

Comment: @user752854: I don't believe it. How are you adding the event handler? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @user752854: Ah I see... yes, `attachEvent` seems to create a problem there. I can only cite quirksmode.org here.

Comment: Why not give precedence to `addEventListener`, if it exists?

Comment: I did.  That's about the best I'll be able to do given what I've read from that quirksmode.org page that you linked to.
`The event handling function is referenced, not copied, so the this keyword always refers to the window and is completely useless.`
Looks like  I'm stuck with this solution.  Thanks a lot though, this will work fine.

Comment: @missingno: You mean testing for it first? I thought it is better to fall back to `addEventListener` than to `attachEvent`. But the order does not really matter. It is only called once at page load anyway.

Comment: @pinktrink: You're welcome! I guess that's the least I could do after not believing you first ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.brainjar.com/dhtml/events/default3.asp) IE simply has no equivalent to `currentTarget`.  Therefore, if you can't find a way to bind the events such that you get the correct element in target/srcElement, you could try adding a class to the element that you want to catch the event and traversing the DOM tree up to this element.

```
<div class="eventCatcher">
    <div id="eventTrigger>More HTML</div>
</div>

<script>
    function catchEvent(event)
    {
        event = event || window.event;
        target = event.target || event.srcElement;

        while (!target.getAttribute('class').indexOf('eventCatcher') >= 0)
            target = target.parentElement;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: All these attributes return different elements (well, `srcElement` and `target` should return the same).

Comment: Not in my experience.  I don't actually use `currentTarget` tbh, but I use `event.target || event.srcElement` in my own code and have yet to find any problems with it.

Comment: But that is not what the OP wants. `target` and `srcElement` refer to the element that triggered the event, not the element that handles it.

Comment: `srcElement` and `target` both refer to the element that **triggered** the event, not the element that **caught** it.  I need the latter.

Comment: @user752854 then use the solution in the first comment on your Q

Comment: @Endophage that's pretty much the exact same as this one.

Comment: Actually, that implementation *would* work, except that IE6 doesn't support indexOf.  You'd have to write that one out in JS as well.

Comment: @pinktrink so why exactly can't you use jQuery?

Comment: @Endophage This was specifically for a framework, meaning that using another framework was out of the question.