# inilne event registration vs. advanced registration for image validation

Tags: javascript

Inline Event Registration works correctly if I use code similar to

```
onerror=function(this) // in xhtml placed in element
```

However advanced event registration does not work, i.e.

```
a.onerror=function(this) // where a. is the element in javascript
```

when I want to correctly update this.src to a new image on fail.

Comment: Please post your code. I assume you are not calling your error handler correctly when using inline event handlers.

Comment: Depends. If we are talking about `onclick="something()"`, then of course, inside `something`, `this` refers to `window`. But this function call is actually *inside* the event handler, where `this` refers to the element. If you call the function "correctly" (with that I mean setting the context properly), like  `onclick="something.call(this)"`, then `this` will refer to the element inside `something`.

Comment: If you have `element.onclick = errorhandler;` then `this` will refer to the `element` as well. Also if you use `addEventListener`. Only with `attachEvent` it will not be the case. If this is your problem, have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985351/event-currenttarget-in-ie6/6985481#6985481

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to use addEventListener