# IE 7/8 Issue - Unable to get value of the property 'id': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I've made an ajax search form that brings up results onkeyup, that works well.

To remove the results if someone clicks anywhere on the page outside the results list i've used currentTarget on a transparent fullscreen div at the top of the page to clear the results.

It works perfectly in ff, ie9, chrome, safari & opera. But when trying it in ie 7 and ie 8 it shows the results but won't remove them. The console is returning this:

**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'id': object is null or undefined**

Any ideas what this could be. I've search for bugs online but it didn't bring anything I could work out.

Comment: Sadly, it looks like you might be out of luck for IE 7/8 support of currentTarget.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857439/internet-explorer-and-javascript-event-currenttarget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.currentTarget` isn't available in IE8 and lower.

Depending on how your handler is bound, you *may* be able to use `this` in place of `currentTarget`.

Answer (score 0):

There are trailing comma's after the last items of arrays/objects, remove them, IE doesn't like trailing commas in arrays/objects. for example

```
{ "date": "2014-08-20 14:40:30", "title": "event 1event", "description": "af sdfa sdfasd ..." }, { "date": "2014-06-30 00:00:00", "title": "event 2", "description": "a sdfa" }, { "date": "2014-06-29 00:00:00", "title": "event 3" },
```

remove last comma as given below

```
{ "date": "2014-08-20 14:40:30", "title": "event 1event", "description": "af sdfa sdfasd ..." }, { "date": "2014-06-30 00:00:00", "title": "event 2", "description": "a sdfa" }, { "date": "2014-06-29 00:00:00", "title": "event 3" }
```

Cheers :)