# Alternate for currentTarget Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tree

I need some help on JavaScript, I need an alternative for currentTarget as my program on JavaScript is not working on Internet Explorer 8, so i need any alternate way which will work on my JavaScript code.The following is some what a part of my code where currentTag is used.

Note :Only JavaScript, not JQUERY.

---

```
     var sortedObject = function (obj) {
        document.getElementById("dvList2").innerHTML = "";
        var ul = document.createElement("ul"),
            li;
        var keys = Object.keys(obj).sort();
        for (prop in keys) {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(keys[prop]));
            li.onclick = function(e) {
                e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("hidden");
                e.stopPropagation();
            }

            if (typeof obj[keys[prop]] == "object" && Objectkeys(obj[keys[prop]]).length) {
                li.appendChild(sortedObject(obj[keys[prop]]));
            } else {
                li.className += "leaf";
            }
            ul.appendChild(li);
            console.log(ul);
        }
        return ul;
    };
```

---

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer and JavaScript event currentTarget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857439/internet-explorer-and-javascript-event-currenttarget)

Comment: See Barmar's link: highly recommended!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target IE8 you should properly change `Object.keys` and `node.classList` as well.

<s>But about the `event.currentTarget` you can use `event.srcElement` for IE8:</s>

```
var target = event.currentTarget || event.srcElement;
```

Hmm... Look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1876316/887539

**Object.keys**

[image]

**node.classList**

[image]

Comment: My code dont have Object.keys, as i did use a small block code for Object.keys, i need help for only currentTarget. please help