# IE8 event.currentTarget is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

There is an incompatibility with IE8 in my Javascript and I am not sure how to resolve it. I am getting an error "currentTarget is null or not an object," which is occurring in this snippet of code:

```
(function() {
  var basicTemplate, _timer, _url;
  _timer = null;
  _url = "/search";
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var search, searchCallback, searchFailure;
    $('[data-does=typeahead-rep-search]').on('keyup', function(e) {
      clearTimeout(_timer);
      return _timer = setTimeout(search, 300, e);
    });
    search = function(e) {
      var $query, division, request, target, _data;
      $query = $(e.currentTarget);
      _data = {};
      if (_data.q.length > 2) {
        return request = $.ajax(_url, {
          data: _data,
          success: searchCallback,
          error: searchFailure
        });
      } else {
        return $('#search-results').html("");
      }
    };
    searchCallback = function(data, status, jqXhr) {
      return $('#search-results').html(basicTemplate(data));
    };
    return searchFailure = function(jqXhr, status, errorThrown) {
      console.log('an error has occurred while attempting to search');
      return $('#search-results').html("");
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

Does anyone know how I can recode this snippet in order to make it function properly in IE?

Thanks!

Comment: `this` should be the same as `e.currentTraget`, assuming it's bound as a typical event handler. How exactly is the function bound, or how is it invoked?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? 2.x removed many IE8 things.

Comment: I am using 1.11.10, I'll give 2.x a shot. @cookie monster, the function is invoked on keyup event if the query is greater than 2 characters. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @user13286: You've got it backwards, if you're supporting IE8 you do not want `2.x`. It's strange that `e.currentTarget` is not defined though.

Comment: `_url` is a global variable too?

Comment: Please show how the `search` function is bound to an event.

Comment: Updated original post with more code. Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas based on the updated code?

Comment: What if instead of using e.currentTarget you just put the ID of the target. $query = $('[data-does=typeahead-rep-search]');

Comment: Hmmm, that does seem to work, but it seems like a band-aid fix. I suppose in my scenario it won't cause any issues though since I am just trying to get the value from that single input field. Does anyone  disagree with solving in this way? Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @user13286 I wish I could be alerted to edits to questions I have an answer on. Sorry I didn't notice your edit earlier. I've added an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and thoughtful answer Joe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem is this line:

```
setTimeout(search, 300, e);
```

The easiest fix would be this:

```
setTimeout((function(e) { return function() { search(e) }; })(e), 300);
```

I've wrapped it in a closure to avoid scoping issues.

From the documentation for [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout):

> Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer < 9. If you want to enable this functionality on that browser, you must use a compatibility code (see the Callback arguments paragraph).

I'm just going to copy this all wholesale from the docs, as a reference here.

> If you need to pass an argument to your callback function, but need it
>   to work in Internet Explorer, which doesn't support sending additional
>   parameters (neither with setTimeout() or setInterval()) you can
>   include this IE-specific compatibility code which will enable the
>   HTML5 standard parameters passage functionality in that browser for
>   both timers just by inserting it at the beginning of your scripts.
>
> ```
> /*\
> |*|
> |*|  IE-specific polyfill which enables the passage of arbitrary arguments to the
> |*|  callback functions of JavaScript timers (HTML5 standard syntax).
> |*|
> |*|  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval
> |*|
> |*|  Syntax:
> |*|  var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
> |*|  var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, delay);
> |*|  var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
> |*|  var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);
> |*|
> \*/
>
> if (document.all && !window.setTimeout.isPolyfill) {
>   var __nativeST__ = window.setTimeout;
>   window.setTimeout = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
>     var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
>     return __nativeST__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
>       vCallback.apply(null, aArgs);
>     } : vCallback, nDelay);
>   };
>   window.setTimeout.isPolyfill = true;
> }
>
> if (document.all && !window.setInterval.isPolyfill) {
>   var __nativeSI__ = window.setInterval;
>   window.setInterval = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
>     var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
>     return __nativeSI__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
>       vCallback.apply(null, aArgs);
>     } : vCallback, nDelay);
>   };
>   window.setInterval.isPolyfill = true;
> }
> ```
>
> IE Only Fix
>
> If you want a completely unobtrusive hack for every other mobile or
>   desktop browser, including IE 9 and above, you can either use
>   JavaScript conditional comments:
>
> ```
> /*@cc_on
>   // conditional IE < 9 only fix
>   @if (@_jscript_version <= 6)
>   (function(f){
>      window.setTimeout =f(window.setTimeout);
>      window.setInterval =f(window.setInterval);
>   })(function(f){return function(c,t){var a=[].slice.call(arguments,2);return
>     f(function(){c.apply(this,a)},t)}});
>   @end
> @*/
> ```
>
> Or go for a very clean approach based on the IE HTML conditional
>   feature:
>
> ```
> <!--[if lt IE 9]><script>
> (function(f){
> window.setTimeout =f(window.setTimeout);
> window.setInterval =f(window.setInterval);
> })(function(f){return function(c,t){
> var a=[].slice.call(arguments,2);return f(function(){c.apply(this,a)},t)}
> });
> </script><![endif]-->
> ```
>
> Another possibility is to use an anonymous function to call your
>   callback, but this solution is a bit more expensive. Example:
>
> ```
> var intervalID = setTimeout(function() { myFunc("one", "two", "three"); }, 1000);
> ```
>
> Yet another possibility is to use function's bind. Example:
>
> ```
> setTimeout(function(arg1){}.bind(undefined, 10));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I resolved the issue by modifying the code as seen below. Please let me know if this is not the recommended method of resolving this issue.

## [SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857439/internet-explorer-and-javascript-event-currenttarget)

```
search = function(e) {
      var $query, division, request, _data;
      var target = (e.currentTarget) ? e.currentTarget : e.srcElement;
      $query = $(target);
      _data = {};
      _data.q = $query.val();
      if (_data.q.length > 2) {
        return request = $.ajax(_url, {
          data: _data,
          success: searchCallback,
          error: searchFailure
        });
      } else {
        return $('#search-results').html("");
      }
    };
```

Comment: That is not the recommended method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857439/internet-explorer-and-javascript-event-currenttarget?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: It is very strange that jQuery did not populate currentTarget for you.

Comment: Is 1.11.10 supposed to do that?