# Backbone click event won't return evt.Target IE8

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, internet-explorer-8

Given the following click handler, I am not able to log e.currentTarget or most of the objects that jQuery typically returns. This is only happening in IE8.

```
    clickHandler: function(evt){
      //do stuff
      console.log('evt: ', evt);
    }
```

If I log the event, I only get a handful of the properties, like so. How can i get the full event?

```
LOG: evt:{
  "type": "click",
  "jQuery111008085261648353432": true,
  "toElement": null,
  "screenY": 465,
  "screenX": 327,
  "pageY": 280,
  "pageX": 278,
  "offsetY": 39,
  "offsetX": 257,
  "fromElement": null,
  "clientY": 280,
  "clientX": 278,
  "button": 0,
  "which": 0,
  "shiftKey": false,
  "metaKey": false,
  "ctrlKey": false,
  "altKey": false,
  "handleObj": {
    "type": "click",
    "origType": "click",
    "guid": 113,
    "selector": "p, li, input, textarea, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, th, td",
    "needsContext": false,
    "namespace": "delegateEventsview103"
  }
}
```

Here is what I have defined for the events:

```
'click p, li, input, textarea, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, th, td' : 'clickHandler'
```

Comment: what types of objects should be accepting the click? What does your events object/function look like?

Comment: I updated it with the click handlers.

Comment: The problem is that there are no objects like evt.currentTarget. Chrome has this however

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer and JavaScript event currentTarget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857439/internet-explorer-and-javascript-event-currenttarget)

Answer (score 1):

try this :
// Support IE6-8

var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

if e.target is not supported (undefined) it return  e.srcElement